# Android BLE LeScanCallback get when stopped

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a dialog that scans for BLE devices for 10 seconds. When I start my scan I enable a spinner at the footer of the list. When the scan is completed I'd like to remove that spinner. I'm trying to get this to work with the deprecated mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(callback) function instead of the new startScan/stopScan functions as if the device isn't running version 21 or higher, you have to fallback to this method.

stopLeScan requires the same callback as startLeScan but I dont think I see the callback being made. I was hoping that it was a simple check to see if the BluetoohDevice was null, then the callback was made because the scan was stopped, but this didn't work.

With the old version of the SDK, how do you get when the scan has been stopped (either due to the proper device being found or the scan time completed)? I could pass another handler to the my scanLeDevice function, but that just seems silly as I'm already passing a callback.

**Bluetooth scanner**

```
public class BleDevice {
    private final static String TAG = BleDevice.class.getSimpleName();

    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public BleDevice() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    public void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable, final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback) {
        if (enable == true && mScanning == false) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Turn off scanning
                    scanLeDevice(false, callback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(callback);
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting Bluetooth LE scan");
        } else if(enable == false && mScanning == true) {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(callback);
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopped Bluetooth LE scan");
        }
    }
}
```

**Callback in Dialog Box:**

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        Log.d(TAG, device.getAddress() + " " + device.getName() + "");
        if(device == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Device is null? stop?");
        } else {
            btAdapter.add(device);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(callback);` the `callback` is just used to identify which scan is to be stopped and it's not supposed to trigger any method in the `callback`. It's a synchronous operation.

And the `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` class doesn't even have any methods beyond the `onLeScan()` which just receives the results.

So, you can define your own method to be triggered when the scan is stopped by you:

```
...
} else if(enable == false && mScanning == true) {
    mScanning = false;
    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(callback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Stopped Bluetooth LE scan");
    onScanStopped(); // <--- Remove the spinner here. 
}
```

I'm not aware of any automatic timeout for `startLeScan()`, so as far as I know it should only stop by calling `stopLeScan()`. And `onLeScan()` being triggered doesn't stop the scan either.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I ended up using an observer pattern and made my own callback